# What's the purpose of these screws in my window screen?

Tags: windows

I notice that window screens often have four screws, located toward each corner of the screen on the vertical portion of the frame. What's the purpose of these screws? Are they used to adjust the width of the window frame slightly? The reason I ask is because my window screen does not stay up, and I am wondering how I might fix that. Note, I have also other window screens without these screws.

[image: My window screen]

Comment: Be careful removing the screen, it will tend to bend and break where the screws are.

Answer (score 1):

I have those on my screen windows and they actually screw into the frame to secure the screen.  Do you have holes in the frame behind those screws?

Comment: No, the screen has a clean rail to slide up and down in. I see, the screws are for situations where you don't want others, from the outside for instance, to move the screen.

Comment: Even without a hole for the screw to go into, @bernie, you could still use that screw by snugging it up against the frame. That should help hold it in place, though it wouldn't be _as_ secure as if there were a hole for the screw to go into. If this is just a "nuisance" level problem, that may well take care of it.

Comment: That's a good idea, although upon trying, I find the screws to be seemingly stuck.

Comment: I don't think the screw serving any purpose other than convenience to move the screen. It is there wasn't by design, but an add-on.

Comment: I agree with @r13, those do not appear to be original equipment. They were installed either as a means to lift/remove the screen, or as a retainer of some sort. That screw is stuck because of frame corrosion around it, which is visible in the picture.

Comment: I think I've seen similar screws in window screens before, although it's true that other screens on my windows don't have these screws. But for this screen, there are four of these, in symmetrical positions, so I'm not 100% about the hypothesis that they were added later. The screen has a little lip at the bottom to lift it, so i don't know about the utility of these screws as "grab handles," but I could understand the retaining purpose.